# How to reduce the number of dynamic memory allocations in OpenSSL 3 generally and RAND_bytes specifically?

Tags: memory, openssl

Consider the following MRE:

```
#include <openssl/rand.h>

int main() {
        unsigned char buf[16];
        return RAND_bytes(buf, 16);
}
```

valgrind'ing this compiled and linked with openssl 1 shows that it calls malloc 32 times:

```
$ valgrind ./a.out
==4904== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4904== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4904== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4904== Command: ./a.out
==4904== 
==4904== 
==4904== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4904==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4904==   total heap usage: 32 allocs, 32 frees, 21,412 bytes allocated
==4904== 
==4904== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==4904== 
==4904== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4904== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

But running the same source code compiled and linked with openssl 3 shows that it calls malloc almost 7,000 times:

```
$ valgrind --tool=memcheck ./a.out
==18334== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==18334== Copyright (C) 2002-2022, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==18334== Using Valgrind-3.20.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==18334== Command: ./a.out
==18334== 
==18334== 
==18334== HEAP SUMMARY:
==18334==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18334==   total heap usage: 6,934 allocs, 6,934 frees, 626,370 bytes allocated
==18334== 
==18334== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==18334== 
==18334== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==18334== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I assume this is because OpenSSL 3 has a much more dynamic "provider" interface.  Are there any suggestions for getting the memory usage in the OpenSSL 3 case down closer to the OpenSSL 1 case?

Tried to load the OpenSSL "null" provider, but even doing that, without loading a random number algorithm or anything else required 2500 mallocs.